# How to create a floating div with mootools?

Tags: html, mootools, floating

I'm using an application (IIPImage) which display an High Resolution Image using a script created with mootools api. I want to insert a floating window in this page. Initially I think to use jquery, BUT I discover that jquery can't coexist with this library, so I need to use mootools to create this floating div. How I can do this? Someone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mootools and jquery can co-exist just fine, given some work - jquery has a `.noConflict()` mode and mootools won't take over $ (since 1.2.2) if it has already been defined and will revert to using `document.id` instead. however, IIPImage seems to have been written for  1.2.0 which is old and buggy and does not care about overwriting $ - upgrade mootools to 1.2.5 and replace mentions of $( with document.id( in the script or add a closure instead like `(function($) {` ... code from the zoomer ... `})(document.id);`

you may need to find any global vars refrences and change them as declared from `var foo =` to `window.foo =` but all in all, it should not really be a drama.

as for the other solution, you can figure it out here http://davidwalsh.name/persistent-header-opacity

this is a small bit of code that enables position: fixed for browsers that don't support it (IE before 8 i think)

have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-D I was  searching an answer like this, I maked many searches on this argument but i was unable a complete answer.